# Slack API Channel.history

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

I have two API calls from a NodeJS file to slack, posting a message via api works well but trying to get a channel history returns JSON `{ error: "channel_not_found", ok: false }`.

The token is hardcoded.

**chat.js**

```
Chat.sendMessage = function (text, callback) {
   slack.api('chat.postMessage', {
          text:text,
          as_user:true,
          channel:'#webhooksapi'
        }, function(err, response){
          callback(null,response);
        });
   }

//Getting error on this function
Chat.getMessage = function (channel, callback){
    slack.api('channels.history', {
        token:apiToken,
        channel:'#webhooksapi'
        }, function(err, response){
            callback(null, response);
        });
   }
```

Comment: Please attach the [channel list](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list)

Comment: According to the api´s manual  "Value passed for channel was invalid." https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history

Comment: Did the channel list command and saw that channels have an Id, got the idea to try that and it worked

Comment: Correct @Jimmie it's unclear: even in the test tab we have "#general" as hint, but if you insert "#general" we have the "Channel not found". The parameter is meant to be a channel Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the api´s manual "Value passed for channel was invalid." [api.slack.com/methods/channels.history](http://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history)

Answer (score 2):

When running channels.history api from slack you need to pass the channel id rather then the name. So in my case `channel: 'C1234567890'`

Comment: Maybe this answer is in the API link that I have provided you ;)

Comment: Yea, thats true! I should read closer, Post an answer and I can mark it :)